# When posting an item is it proper form to do a get on the item rather than try to push the ID back to the result?

Tags: c#, rest, post, webapi

I'm using `System.Net.Http.HTTPClient` and in some sample code from a new Xmanarin project I've got a method that works fine. My question is: is this the generally accepted method of getting an object back to the caller?

```
 public async Task<bool> AddItemAsync(Item item)
 {
     if (item == null || !IsConnected)
         return false;

     var serializedItem = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);

     var response = await client.PostAsync($"api/item", new StringContent(serializedItem, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

     /// dig out the URI and fetch it back to be restful...
     var json = await client.GetStringAsync(response.Headers.Location);
     item= await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item>(json));
             
     return response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
  }
```

Comment: Question is more about REST’ish / design, and is not specific to .NET Core x. Code could effectively be written in sh and cURL.

Comment: @user2864740 it is still a good question in webapi because we have to understand what the default expectation of the code is.

Comment: I presented no suggestion on this being a being good / not-good question. The original tags were prime for updates.

Answer (score 1):

> **TL;DR**: Whilst it seems in-efficient, this pattern keeps the client code base very simple and allows for the server to manipulate the resource in other ways after applying business logic/rules.

## should you re-get a resource immediately after a `PUT`/`POST`?

This is not limited to *creation* events, the first point addresses a create request.

- If there is limited or no server-side processing related to your post, so a call to `GET` the same resource immediately after the `POST` will have the exact same content, or you can easily update the changes on the client side then you are only slowing down the user experience by waiting for the same data to come back

  - If the uri to a resource (so the Id/key) can be determined from the response then you may simply be able to parse that value from the `Location` or other headers in the response and update the resource on the client accordingly.
- Some APIs will actually return the content of the resource in the response body itself, or will have an option that you can send as a header on the request to include the content as well. If your API is already returning the content in that response, and that response structure matches the one your app requires, then calling an immediate `GET` again has no value.

  - Look into the Prefer [Header options](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7240) for your API, [OData v4 prefer header](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part1-protocol/odata-v4.0-os-part1-protocol.html#_Toc372793624) supports `return=representation` that will return the resource in the response.

As a general client-side pattern, to call a `GET` immediately after a *create*  or *update* is less code than trying to inject Ids and datestamps into the object, it means you implicitly support the concept that business logic on the API may have modified your resource (provided an Id in the very least) so is very resilient to evolution on the API itself.

As a general rule create operations happen in-frequently in many application designs so although it is less efficient in terms of bandwidth it is an acceptable cost to keeping the code clean and manageable.

## Can you always use `response.Headers.Location` to identify the resource

Usually with webapi this is a reliable REST standard convention to start with, but keep reading...

> in regard to Web API / REST there are many server-side libraries and conventions that ***CAN*** be used that will affect the default behaviour from a server point of view, usually they will return a correct *Location* header in the response to standard *CRUD* requests
>
> > *but that doesn't mean that the developer used these built in behaviours, or didn't override them!*
>
> - This discussion highlights the argument from an API point of view:
>   [REST response - should I put the URL of the new resource in the header, body, or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11159583/1690217)
> - Ultimately the API developer can affect what the content and headers are for *EACH INDIVIDUAL REQUEST* so you really need to consult the API documentation or the developer to know for sure.

Having decided that you *do* need to refresh the resource, if your API url conventions mean that the *Location* of response to a POST is always the uri to retrieve that resource, then by all means continue to use the code you have, just be aware that not all APIs, and not all requests are the same.